# Copy incorrect words in excel

Tags: excel, string, dictionary, text, ms-office

I need to find and **copy** a word(s) in a string. The condition is that the word is an incorrect one. Essentially, it's something like copy all words that has wiggle red underline in browser,MS Words, etc.

I am doing this to extract the brand names in hundred of thousand of free text cells. Since the brand names are usually not words in dictionary (for searchability and identifiablity) , this approach would help find the majority of them.

It doesn't have to be an excel functionality, I am open to any tool that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving them directly into excel is tedious, shown by the link in the previous answer. If you would like a generated list of the misspelled words, follow the instructions on this site:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/a-word-macro-that-highlights-and-lists-misspelled-words/

The code copies the misspelled words into a new document for you, so they will be isolated from your original document. Then you can apply any formatting or data analyses if you need it.

Comment: I think this is the exact way to go. But I am currently still running the script. It took along time, I don't even know what the result is. When I have it, I will update.

Comment: I have marked this as a correct answer. However, it doesn't help my problem. I ran the script but it ended up crashing MS Words. I reduce the number of word in the original document, it worked. But with the document with more than 100K of words, it crashed. I will post another question regarding the specific VBA to find out why it crashed.